# Django: No such file or directory found

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-2.0

so I am in development for a Django website. I feel like this is such a simple fix but for the life of me I can't find a solution. I know where the error is stemming from; on my `index.html` I am trying to show cover images for each blog post. When I remove the line where I call the object's image from the view the site runs. But when it is there I get this error: 
[image]

I have my file structure as follows:
project/media/images (the image error.jpg is in the images folder.

Here is my `settings.py` as I feel like this is where the problem is stemming from (at least the section I think the error is coming from.

Any help at all is greatly appreciated, thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error says:

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\lukem\Software-Dev\drugEdu\media\media\images\error.jpg'

The point I can note from this is that it's looking in

`\\drugEdu\\media\\media\\images\\error.jpg`

instead of

`\\drugEdu\\media\\images\\error.jpg'`

I don't understand your full project structure to locate the exact bug but I believe it may be coming from either the `Media_URL` or `Media_ROOT` declarations. Can you try removing media value inside those variables and see it that works.